# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of null

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a simple web app and I receive the above error. Would you guys please lend me a hand?

app.js:

```
var movieApp = movieApp || {};

(function () {
movieApp.controller = {
    init:function() {
        movieApp.router.init();
        movieApp.section.init();
    }
};

movieApp.router = {
    init:function() {
        routie({
            '/about': function() {
                movieApp.section.toggle('section[data-route="about"]');
            },              
            '/movies': function() {
                movieApp.section.toggle('section[data-route="movies"]');
            },
            ' ': function() {
                movieApp.section.toggle('section[data-route="about"]');
            },  
        });
    }
};

movieApp.content = {
    about: {
        title: "About this app",
        description: "...",
    },

    movies: [
        {
            title: "Shawshank Redemption",
            releaseDate: "14 October 1994",
            description: "Two imprisoned men bond over a number of years, finding solace and eventual redemption through acts of common decency.",
            cover: "../WebApp/static/images/shawshank-redemption.jpg"
        },
        {
            title: "The Godfather",
            releaseDate:"24 March 1972",
            description:"The aging patriarch of an organized crime dynasty transfers control of his clandestine empire to his reluctant son.",
            cover: "../WebApp/static/images/the-godfather.jpg"
        },
        {
            title: "Pulp Fiction",
            releaseDate: "14 October 1994",
            description: "The lives of two mob hit men, a boxer, a gangster's wife, and a pair of diner bandits intertwine in four tales of violence and redemption.",
            cover: "../WebApp/static/images/pulp-fiction.jpg"
        },
        {
            title: "The Dark Knight",
            releaseDate: "18 July 2008",
            description: "When Batman, Gordon and Harvey Dent launch an assault on the mob, they let the clown out of the box, the Joker, bent on turning Gotham on itself and bringing any heroes down to his level.",
            cover: "../WebApp/static/images/the-dark-knight.jpg"
        }
    ]
};

movieApp.section = {
    init:function() {
        this.about();
        this.movies();
    },

    about:function() {
        var aboutSection = {
            'title': movieApp.content.about.title,
            'description': movieApp.content.about.description
        };

        Transparency.render(document.querySelector('section[data-route="about"]'),aboutSection);
    },

    movies:function() {
        var moviesSection = {
            'header': "Favorite Movies",
            'movies': movieApp.content.movies
        }

        // dit zorgt ervoor dat de src van img tag veranderd naar wat er staat in this.cover
        var directives = {
            movies: {
                cover: {
                    src: function(params){
                        return this.cover
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        Transparency.render(document.querySelector('section[data-route="movies"]'),moviesSection, directives);
    },

    toggle:function(section) {
        section = typeof section !== 'undefined' ? section : 'section[data-route="about"]';
        document.querySelector(section).classList.toggle('active');
    }
};

movieApp.controller.init();

})();
```

The html file looks like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Movies Web App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="static/stylesheets/main.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#/about">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#/movies">Movies</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>

    <main id="content">

        <section data-route="about">
            <header>
                <h1 data-bind="title"></h1>
                <p data-bind="description"></p>
            </header>
        </section>

        <section data-route="movies">
            <h1 data-bind="header"></h1>    
            <div data-bind="movies">
                <article data-bind="movie">
                    <header>
                        <h1 data-bind="title"></h1>
                        <em><time data-bind="releaseDate"></time></em>
                    </header>
                    <figure>
                        <img data-bind="cover" src="" alt="">
                    </figure>
                    <p data-bind="description"></p>
                </article>
            </div>
        </section>
    </main>

    <script src="static/js/lib/routie.js"></script>
    <script src="static/js/lib/transparency.js"></script>
    <script src="static/js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

When I run the index page, I get the following error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of null.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: So obviously `document.querySelector(section)` is `null` - Check the value of `section`

Comment: I did console.log(this.section) and I get undefined. How can I solve this?

Comment: Your `toggle` is designed to take an argument `section`. If you call `toggle` somewhere without argument, `document.querySelector(section) == null`.

Comment: But don't I pass the argument above @: 'about': function() {
        movieApp.section.toggle('section[data-route="about"]');
       },

Comment: @Matt - `section` is an argument, not a property of the calling context. Try `console.log(section);` immediately before your `document.querySelector(...)` line.

Comment: That gives me undefined as a result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this section `this` is equivalent to `movieApp.section`.

```
movieApp.section = {
    init:function() {
        this.about();
        this.movies();
        this.toggle();
    },
};
```

So `this.toggle()` is calling `movieApp.section.toggle()` and is then not passing a parameter to that function.

If you wanted to set a default active class on the 'about' section you would need to do this to your function:

```
toggle:function(section) {
    section = typeof section !== 'undefined' ? section : 'section[data-route="about"]';
    document.querySelector(section).classList.toggle('active');
}
```

**UPDATE**

As per the comments you can just remove the `toggle` line from here:

```
movieApp.section = {
    init:function() {
        this.about();
        this.movies();
    },
};
```

Comment: Richie, thanks for the reply. I just changed this.toggle to movieApp.section.toggle and I receive this error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of null

Comment: You still need to pass a parameter to `toggle()`.  It expects the parameter `section`, and passes this parameter into 'querySelectorAll`.  If `section` is `undefined` then `querySelectorAll()` will return `null` and you will not be able to get a `classList` from `null`.

Comment: I'm sorry bro. Been working on this project for a long time. I can't see it anymore. What do I need to change to make it work the way I want it to work?

Comment: I've updated my answer. You've not made it clear in your question how you want it to work but I'm assuming you want to set an `active` class on one of the sections by default when the app is loaded.  If that's the case then the update should work.

Comment: Richie, thanks! The error message is gone. But the about page is still not showing up by default.

Comment: Just remove the `movieApp.section.toggle();` - having had a longer look I'm not sure what it's there for in that section of the code.  Routie seems to be handling the toggle when on a base url.  You can also remove the `active` parameter from `toggle` when your setting up route on `' '`.

Comment: Updated - use your old code but remove the toggle line.

Comment: Updated the code see my first post. Still no active about section. The active class has been added to the section element. But css is still display:none; for that element when the page is loaded.

Comment: Thank you Richie! I made a mistake  (an extra semicolon) in my css. Everything works. I still have a lot to learn. 
If you could help me with one last thing. When I click on the about page I want the active class to be removed from the movies page, and vice versa.

Comment: No problem, when you toggle you want to remove the class from all elements with ['data-route'], so try adding this as the first line of your `toggle` function: `document.querySelectorAll('section[data-route]').classList.remove('active');` Additionally, if my answer helped you would you mark it as accepted.  Thanks.

Comment: I now have it like this: 
  toggle:function(section) {
            document.querySelectorAll('section[data-route]').classList.remove('active');
            section = typeof section !== 'undefined' ? section : 'section[data-route="about"]';
            document.querySelector(section).classList.toggle('active');
        }
Now the toggle isn't working.

Comment: You also need to loop through them: `toggle: function (section) {
            var els = document.querySelectorAll('section[data-route]');
            for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
                els[i].classList.remove('active');
            };
            document.querySelector(section).classList.toggle('active');
        }`

Comment: Richie, I want to thank you for going the extra mile with me! Everything is working. Thank you for that!

Comment: No problem - try and get so more  rep so we can move these convos into chat next time!